# Dynamic throws RuntimeBinderException although the property exists

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.7.2

I am having a weird situation where I have a `RuntimeBinderException` thrown when trying to access a property although I know for sure it exists (and the debugger shows so):

[image]

The `dictionary` is `Dictionary<int, CraftData>`. However, the type is from a loaded Assembly through Reflection so I cannot cast directly. According to the exception, it seems `value` is still being treated as `object` (I tried `dynamic value = item.Value` but it didn't work too).

Weirdly enough, I try to reproduce it in a new project but there is no exception:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This works
        var objFromReflection = (object) new Foo();
        var dyn = objFromReflection as dynamic;
        Console.WriteLine(dyn.KnownProperty);

        // This also works but it does not work the same in my project
        IDictionary dictFromReflection = new Dictionary<int, Foo>() { { 1, new Foo() }, { 2, new Foo() } };
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in dictFromReflection)
        {
            var key = (int)item.Key;
            var value = item.Value as dynamic;
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {value.KnownProperty}");
        }
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string KnownProperty { get; set; } = "A";
    public string OtherProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

So my questions:

- Why does my standalone code work but the real one above does not?
- Is there anyway to get `craftAmount` without using Reflection?

My current workaround:

- Use Reflection to get the property value.
- Use `JsonConvert` and use `JObject` (I know this is dumb).

Comment: In your example you got 2 nested foreach loops. Your example code only has 1. So not a syntactic equivalent.

Comment: If you don't have the assembly compile time, isn't reflection a good fit here?

Comment: @Christopher the error occur before the nested loop starts.

Comment: @bas yeah it is, but I got the real object already (as in, when the Assembly is loaded, it loads the values also). True, I can use Reflection, but it's nice if I can skip it and access them directly as I could in the example.

Comment: Just because it comes later, does not mean it will not affect things. If anything something not being used, tends to allow teh JiT and Compilter to cut it out as dead code. Also the error might actually be in the preceeding Collection, not this one. You also access a totally different Property. With such a thing it is easy to not make the same mistake.